# Отсутствует доступ к публичном полям родительского интерфейса напрямую

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим у меня есть интерфейс

```cs
public interface IHasInvertory
{
    protected Invertory _invertory { get; set; }

    public Invertory invertory
    {
        get => _invertory;
        set {
            if (_invertory != null)
                _invertory.Owner = null;
            _invertory = value;
            _invertory.Owner = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Он имеет поле `_invertory` (который никогда не должен быть использован вручную) и поле `invertory`, который и является тем самым полем, с которым можно спокойно взаимодействовать.

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь унаследовать данный интерфейс, то я **не могу получить прямой доступ к полю `invertory`**:

```cs
public class Player : Creature, IHasInvertory
{
    Invertory IHasInvertory._invertory { get; set; }

    protected override void Start()
    {
        ((IHasInvertory)this).invertory.Items.Clear(); // Работает
        this.invertory.Items.Clear(); // Ошибка???
        base.Start();
        Controller = new PlayerController();
    }
}
```

Почему так происходит, и как этого избежать?

**P. S.**: Версия Unity: `2022.3.7f1` (последняя 2022), версия `C#` вроде бы `9.0`

**P. S. 2**: Проверил, не работает даже на последних версиях `C#`...

Comment: Текст ошибки  какой?

Comment: @tym32167 Да буквально поле не существует (`Имя "invertory" не существует в данном контексте`)

Comment: Я не пишу давненько на сишарпе, но из быстрого гуглежа я понял, что это так задумано по дизайну. Поскольку в сишарпе есть множественное наследование интерфейсов, то чтобы вызвать метод или свойство реализованное в интерфейсе, надо к нему конкретно приводиться. Чуть подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75782316/312041) и в [доке](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods).

Comment: @tym32167 Выглядит как кривое решение... Можно было бы сделать обращение при единичном наличии данного поля, ну или хотя бы через `this<Interface>.field` как это происходит при объявлении методов...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В интерфейсах должно быть только `public`, это суть его существования, быть инструкцией для пользования кем-то, скрывая способ реализации под абстракцией! То есть `private` там быть не должно от слова "совсем", как и `protected`.

---

**В ИНТЕРФЕЙСАХ НЕТ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ !!! "Реализация" в интерфейсе это просто шаблон для автозаполнения в классе, который будет реализовывать этот интерфейс, с наследованием никак не связан!**

Если `protected` поле в интерфейсе тебе понадобилось для написания шаблона то:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот как он должен выгдядеть:

```
public interface IInvertoryMaster
{
    public IInvertory Invertory { get; }
}
```

---

Если в твоему инвенторе требуется поле `Owner`, то скорее всего это костыль и ты что-то делаешь не то. `set` инвенторя вообще выглядет подозрительным методом. Зачем вообще может понадобиться передача инвенторя? Хрень какае-то! Зуб даю на отсечение, кепку на стол, что там должна быть передача содержимого, а не инвентаря!!!

Comment: public не поможет, ничего не изменится, а вот на счёт set и вправду что то сглупил. Изначально он существовал для инициализации инвентаря при инициализации объекта, но никто не мешает такое запихнуть его в конструктор например... В общем согласен)

А вот на счёт `protected` в интерфейсе... ну хз. Предоставляя внешнее взаимодействие интерфейс так же может и содержать логику для преобразования...

Comment: Ну а поле owner скорее существует для удобства и сокращения кода (например нет необходимости хранить открытый инвентарь как владельца этого инвентаря), а хранить `IHasInvertory` не варик, потому что инвентари тоже разные бывают (производные классы от `Inventory`), и постоянно прописывать `((PlayerInventory)parent.inventory)` неудобно

Comment: В интерфейсах нет никакой логики! Это просто шаблон который автоматически пропишется в классе, это не наследование. Просто синтаксический сахр.

Comment: К сожалению приходится идти на такие (для многих) костыли из за отсутствия множественного наследования... Не хочется в половине классов дополнительно реализовывать много лишней логики...

Comment: Не, ну вообще есть ещё вариант через рефлексию проверять наличие поля `Inventory`))))

Comment: *например нет необходимости хранить открытый инвентарь как владельца этого инвентаря*... что? Вроде знаю где тут ставить запятую, но смысла в фразе всё равно не появляется. Рефлексией можно всё и она может быть самый большой костыль-красная кнопка, но использовать её ради шаблона??? Где та картинка фейспалма, в которой эмодзи себе голову прошибает? Повторяю, это не наследование!!!

Comment: Видов инвенторя не много, списочный и индексированный, ну и по ключу в особых ситуациях. Отличаются устройством хранения. Что за `PlayerInventory` и почему инвентарь зависит от владельца, боюсь спросить, DI отдыхает в сторонке.

Comment: Ну глобально он делится на `список` и `сетку` предметов. От него уже идут производные: `Инвентарь игрока` (отдельные слоты для снаряжения/вооружения и т. п.), `Магазин` (дополнительные поля для слотов в виде стоимости), вражеские инвентари (например инвентарь турели, поддерживающий только патроны), инвентарь сундука, инвентарь трупа и так далее. При этом каждый из таких инвентарей наследуется от единого типа, что позволяет выполнять на них общие методы (например проверка на наличие определённого предмета), позволяя сделать систему поиска вещей в округе и не только

Comment: Да. лоудаут эквипа юнита, это тоже инвентарь, но удобнее его сводить и индексированному присвоив слотам индексы. 
Полезно использовать на добавление `Predicate<Item>` и `Predicate<int>` для индексируемого и метод `bool CanAdd(Item item)/(Item item, int index)`.
Для эквипа, каждый индекс это прописанный тип слота, а для инвенторя турели или любой сумки патронов, проверка на тип предмета (`ammo`) и не нужно создавать новый сабкласс, а просто указать условие. 
Такое количество разных реализаций инвенторя странное, не практичное и не удобное решение, в AAA rpg играх меньше реализаций инвенторя)

Comment: Ну вообще это понятно, я тут немного преувеличил. Разумеется для половины задач (любые хранилища) я буду использовать дефолтный `GridInventory`, а для другой половины (лут с трупов, вещи врагов) `ListInventory` (ну или ещё одна единая простая модификация `ListInventory` для всех живых сущностей). Но всё равно останутся ситуации, где без сабкласса будет слишком неудобно (как я уже упоминал: магазин, инвентарь игрока), да и в будущем могут появится ещё какие ни будь непредвиденные типы.

Comment: А на счёт владельца, как я уже упоминал он особо не нужен, только для облегчения кода. Например глобальная система `InventoryGS` которая управляет интерфейсом получает игрока через глобальную систему `MainPlayerGS` и пытается открыть инвентарь полученной сущности (если он имеется). В данном случае гораздо легче хранить сам инвентарь, а не его владельца. Все подробности расписывать не хочу, выше был пример